# Page Reference and If Statement

Tags: apex, soql, pagereference, code

I am looking to add another if/or statement that will also look for if the phone number is Anonymous to be redirected to the contact page. Here is what I have. It is working but I need to add Anonymous or 9999999999 as phone number criteria. Please assist

```
List<contact> lstContact = [SELECT Id,Case_Skill__c,caseRcordTypeName__c FROM Contact WHERE Phone =: strPhoneNumber];
if(lstContact.isEmpty()) // throw user for new contact page {
   Id conRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Default Contact').getRecordTypeId();
   pagereference pr = new pagereference('/lightning/o/Contact/new?defaultFieldValues=Case_Skill__c='+strSkillName+',MobilePhone='+ strPhoneNumber+',caseRcordTypeName__c='+caseRecordTypeName);
   return pr;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Above is just a snippet of the code. The phone number is being stored in strPhoneNumber. I would like if the phone number = Anonymous or 999999999 to record the number on the contact but route to create a new contact. The code above is looking for if the phone number is empty but I would like to look for empty phone numbers and anonymous phone numbers.